# Font is not applying on CheckBox and Switch Android Studio 3

Tags: java, android, xml

After updating to Android Studio 3 and using the latest SDK and build tools there is a feature to add fonts to the `fonts` folder under resources and use it directly in xml or java. I'm using this code in my theme in `styles.xml` to apply theme on my whole application

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iransansfont</item>
```

it's working on `Button`, `TextView`, and pretty much everything except `CheckBox` and `Switch` widgets. I even tried `fontFamily` on my `CheckBox`s and `Switch`s but it's not working either. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to set fonts on CheckBoxes (and some other widgets) with font resources via XML.
You can do it programmatically instead:

```
checkBox.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.your_font));
```

This issue has been reported on the Android bug tracker, star it to get it fixed soon: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63250768

Comment: The problem still exists in 2019 (api=28) and this is still a workable solution.

Comment: Also you can use Calligraphy library for changing font of all widgets.

Comment: The issue is marked as "Fixed", but still happening on 2023 using "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1"...